# How to correctly interpret MiniProfiler timings logged by SqlServerStorage?

Tags: asp.net, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a simple request that is being profiled, listed below.

```
public MyResponse GetOrders(OrdersRequest request)
{
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
    using (profiler.Step("GetOrders Service Requests"))
    {
        using (profiler.Step("_externalRepository.GetOrders"))
        {

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

That yields the following rows in the database when executed.

[image: sql query of method]

So my question is how does the DurantionMilliseconds for the root object correlate to the timings of it's children? I see 73.400 and assume this is the total across this operation, is that correct?

Versions:

```
<package id="MiniProfiler" version="3.0.10-beta7" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="MiniProfiler.EF5" version="3.0.10-beta1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a Timing step's duration includes its children Timings' durations.

It's easier to visualize as a tree*:

```
> http://localhost:8203/ExternalService.svc   73.4 ms
>> GetOrders Service Requests                 56.1 ms
>>> _externalRepository.GetOrders             55.9 ms
```

So the root timing (i.e. the entire request) took 73.4 ms; `GetOrders Service Requests` was 56.1 ms of that entire 73.4 ms; and `_externalRepository.GetOrders` was 55.9 ms of its parent's 56.1 ms.

<sub>* the MiniProfiler extension method [`RenderPlainText()`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfilerExtensions.cs#L189) can output this format.</sub>

Comment: Still relevant after 5 years!